# How to approach new job salary negotiation when current job pays nearly half of industry average?

Tags: interviewing, salary, job-offer, negotiation

I am a business analysis/BI manager at a small-to-medium sized company that has seen huge international growth. I progressed here since finishing my higher education and have built some seniority, although there are certain factors that are making the job less enjoyable than when I started (change in management, restructuring, stifled career development) most importantly the salary is low compared to rest of the industry.

Doing a search online, the average salary for jobs that match or are even lower responsibility than my current profile pay nearly double my job.

I think this is partly due to the fact that the company grew from scratch rather than being an established one, and I know many others have left and got much higher salaries.

One of the main reasons I want to leave is thus salary. As I emphasized in my other question, I have numerous problems in my life that make it paramount for me to significantly increase my income. I am just a bit unsure whether I will be able to get the full potential, or if recruiters and HR will calculate my new job salary by taking into account my previous salary.

What is the best I can do to ensure my next job salary will not be reduced due to my current one?

I fear that at some point during interviewing, I will be asked what my current salary is and that might be used as a basis for their offer.

Comment: State that you want to leave because of your salary and I like to probe and ask what the salary range for the position is, most recruiters will tell you the range as it affects their commission too.  Higher range is better, regardless of what you make.

Answer (score 3):

Your next salary is dictated by you as well as any future employer. Don't accept an offer you already know you will be unhappy with.

You need to set the pace in negotiations, don't allow the salary discussion to centre around simply being better than your current job if that is so poorly paid comparatively to the rest of the industry.

Instead show that you understand the market value of your profession *and your current level within that profession* and that you expect a salary offer to be made accordingly. At that point you're just stating facts rather than arguing for some kind of massive raise out of thin air, and if a new employer was expecting to offer a salary for their role that's along the lines of 'fair market value' and you go in and ask for fair market value, it shouldn't be too painful to reach an agreement.

Comment: I'd add that due to psychological "anchoring" effects, OP should avoid mentioning his/her current salary first.  Make sure your expected salary and reasoning is laid out first, and only if prompted/asked, then mention your current salary.  The disparity can then be explained as a deviation from that baseline, expected salary (the "anchor").